# How to adjust android gradient background?

Tags: android, background, gradient

To create a default linear gradient background, I do this

```
<gradient android:angle="0"
    android:startColor="#EC3937"
    android:endColor="#BED73F"
    android:type="linear"
    />
```

to produce this:

[image]

Is there a way or hack to adjust the blend (color mix) in linear gradient background as such:

[image: gradient background 1][image: gradient background 2][image: gradient background 3][image: gradient background 4]

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust it by using android:centerX="" or android:centerY="". For example, I used the next code to make the gradient in the image. For my didn't work really well using just the center parameters so I opted for adding a center color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#FFBE5E"
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:centerColor="@color/white"
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerX="0.85"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

[Gradient Drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKzV4.png)

These codes might work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:centerX="0.25"
        android:startColor="#EC3937"
        android:centerColor="#BED73F"
        android:endColor="#BED73F"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:centerX="0.25"
        android:startColor="#EC3937"
        android:centerColor="#BED73F"
        android:endColor="#BED73F"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#EC3937"
        android:endColor="#BED73F"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:centerX="0.50"
        android:startColor="#EC3937"
        android:centerColor="#EC3937"
        android:endColor="#BED73F"
        android:type="linear" />
 </shape>
```